# IT IS SHOWING THAT PROCEDURE CREATED WITH COMPILATION ERROR?

Tags: plsql

```
/* PROCEDURE */
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
    DECLARE
    A NUMBER;
    B NUMBER;
    SUM NUMBER:=0;
    PROCEDURE ADDD(X IN NUMBER,Y IN NUMBER,SUM OUT NUMBER) AS
    BEGIN
    SUM:=X+Y;
    END;
    BEGIN
    A:=12;
    B:=54;
    ADDD(A,B,SUM);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUM);
    END;
    /
```

Comment: It appears that you have a problem with your keyboard. The CAPS LOCK KEY seems to be stuck. I'd suggest you go out and buy a new one, then come back here and [edit] your question so that it's more clear. (Maybe whatever IT is got confused by all the CAPS too.) When you do so, you can include the actual error message you're seeing; it's right on the screen in front of you, but unfortunately we can't see your screen from where we're sitting.

Comment: Why even you need procedure and anonymous block this???? It can be done simply by SELECT var1 + var 2 v_sum from dual;